# Angular 6 external js,css reference not working

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular6

I am working with angular6.i have a bootstrap admin dashboard template. I am trying to import that template in angular application but external js reference is not taken inside the Angular help how to import and how to refer the external Js/CSS in angular 6 project help!!

I have tried placing all the CSS and js inside the angular.json file. "styles": [], "scripts":[] are
not a working.
Have observed there is no error in the browser console.

```
 "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "assets/css/font-awesome.min.css",
              "assets/css/metisMenu.css",
              "assets/css/typography.css",
              "assets/css/default-css.css",
              "assets/css/styles.css",
              "assets/css/responsive.css"

            ],
            "scripts": [
              "assets/js/vendor/jquery-2.2.4.min.js",
              "assets/js/metisMenu.min.js",
              "assets/js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js",
              "assets/js/jquery.slicknav.min.js",
              "assets/js/scripts.js",
              "assets/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"
            ]
```

#Angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "MDProject": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "targets": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/MDProject",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets" 

            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "assets/css/font-awesome.min.css",
              "assets/css/metisMenu.css",
              "assets/css/typography.css",
              "assets/css/default-css.css",
              "assets/css/styles.css",
              "assets/css/responsive.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "assets/js/vendor/jquery-2.2.4.min.js",
              "assets/js/metisMenu.min.js",
              "assets/js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js",
              "assets/js/jquery.slicknav.min.js",
              "assets/js/scripts.js",
              "assets/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "MDProject:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "MDProject:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "MDProject:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "MDProject-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "targets": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "MDProject:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "MDProject:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "MDProject"
}
```

Let me know where I have gone wrong..

Comment: What path did you give for that Template?

Comment: assests folder path

Comment: Any eg. of the path that you supplied?

Comment: update my question @SiddAjmera

Comment: I guess, that you have not restarted your application. If you are doing any changes inside angular.json, you mush re-start/re-server your app.

Comment: @Anjum....i done but same

Answer (score 0):

Use "assets" key for assets, styles for styles, and scripts for scripts...

```
       "assets": [
          "src/assets",
          "src/favicon.ico"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "assets/css/font-awesome.min.css",
          "assets/css/metisMenu.css",
          "assets/css/typography.css",
          "assets/css/default-css.css",
          "assets/css/styles.css",
          "assets/css/responsive.css"

        ],
        "scripts": [
          "assets/js/vendor/jquery-2.2.4.min.js",
          "assets/js/metisMenu.min.js",
          "assets/js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js",
          "assets/js/jquery.slicknav.min.js",
          "assets/js/scripts.js",
          "assets/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"
        ]
```

**Update:** Change **"targets"** to **"architect"**

```
  {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "MDProject": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/MDProject",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets" 

            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "assets/css/font-awesome.min.css",
              "assets/css/metisMenu.css",
              "assets/css/typography.css",
              "assets/css/default-css.css",
              "assets/css/styles.css",
              "assets/css/responsive.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "assets/js/vendor/jquery-2.2.4.min.js",
              "assets/js/metisMenu.min.js",
              "assets/js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js",
              "assets/js/jquery.slicknav.min.js",
              "assets/js/scripts.js",
              "assets/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "MDProject:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "MDProject:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "MDProject:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "MDProject-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "targets": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "MDProject:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "MDProject:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "MDProject"
}
```

Comment: "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css",
              "src/assets/css/metisMenu.css",
              "src/assets/css/typography.css",
              "src/assets/css/default-css.css",
              "src/assets/css/styles.css",
              "src/assets/css/responsive.css"              
            ]

Comment: like this??@Mikijail Salazar

Comment: Can you update your question adding your complete package.json structure?

Comment: package.json or angular.json @Mikijali salazar

Comment: Update my question @Mikijali Salazar

Comment: @Jose, I just updated the answer. Tray to change "targets" to "architect".. Maybe this link will help you to understand more about that property https://medium.com/dailyjs/angular-cli-6-under-the-hood-builders-demystified-f0690ebcf01

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182400/discussion-between-jose-and-mikjail-salazar).